# How to handle errors in view controller in the MVVM model

Tags: ios, swift, rx-swift, moya, rx-cocoa

Following is my code to make a request and bind it to a UI element

```
func signUpService(_ signUpButtonTap: Observable<Void>, _ userAndPassword: Observable<(String, String)>) -> Observable<Response> {
    return signUpButtonTap
        .withLatestFrom(userAndPassword)
        .flatMapLatest{
            input ->  Observable<Response> in
            return Observable.create { observer in
                let userData = Creator()
                userData?.username = input.0
                userData?.password = input.1
                return provider.request(.signUp(userData!)).filter(statusCode: 201).subscribe{  event -> Void in

                    switch event {
                    case .next(let response):
                        observer.onNext(response)
                        print("Success response", response)

                    case .error(let error):
                        let moyaError: MoyaError? = error as? MoyaError
                        let response: Response? = moyaError?.response
                        let statusCode: Int? = response?.statusCode
                        print("Error response", response?.statusCode)
                        observer.onError(AuthenticationError.server)

                    default:
                        break
                    }

                }
            }
        }.observeOn(MainScheduler.instance)
}
```

In my view I am doing the following

```
self.viewModel.signedUp?.bind{response in
            self.displayPopUpForSuccessfulLogin()
            }.addDisposableTo(disposeBag)
    }
```

Whenever I hit the error block the app crashes. It says Binding error. I am not able to bind error to the UI element.

How are errors handled in Rxswift bindings.
If I get a nil response from the sever how can I handle it.

Any help will be appreciated . Thank you

Comment: Do you have the code for self.displayPopUpForSuccessfulLogin()? you should be using driver not observable, I think that your request is erroring out